# How Create corner radius custom dialog android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have a "Message.java" java class that extends Dialog

```
public class InBoxMessageCustomDialogClass extends Dialog {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog_inbox_message);
}
```

and "message_style" my dialog style :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="sfsdfsdfsd" />
```

and my activity is :

```
InBoxMessageCustomDialogClass dialogClass = new InBoxMessageCustomDialogClass(getContext(),

    dialogClass.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogClass.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogClass.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialogClass.show();
```

how can I make this dialog style like corner dialog?

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview) may help you or this [one](https://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial)

change your layout like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You create drawable: res/drawable/dialog_bg:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>
     <corners
        android:radius="30dp" />
     <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
  </shape>
  ```
- In layout_dialog_inbox_message:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="sfsdfsdfsd" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- When you use:

  ```
  InBoxMessageCustomDialogClass dialogClass = new 
  InBoxMessageCustomDialogClass(getContext(),

  dialogClass.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  dialogClass.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
  ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
  dialogClass.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
  dialogClass.show();
  ```
- Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm so confused because I have tested this way but not worked. This time works very well. tanks for your help.

Comment: what you tested on the device?

Comment: Nox emulator with API 19

Answer (score -1):

Use `CardView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
```

`//view Inside`
`</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`

and add `card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"` to give corner radius.